# How can I implement Instagram photos/feed from a specific user in my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, instagram

I was wondering how I can implement the latest photos from a specific Instagram account in a UIScrollView in my iPhone app, without using a UIWebView and go directly to Instagram.com/USERNAME. I am thinking that the implementation should de something like the Instagram feed in Flipboard. So far I have just used a WebView that goes directly to a website with a rss feed.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question... forgive me. 
Any code and/or would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with UITableView and Auto Layout.

Regarding implementation of the instagram feed UI, you could take a look at [STXDynamicTableView](https://github.com/2359media/STXDynamicTableView) which is a sample code of the same problem that you might be having, which is outlined in a blog post here: [Rebuilding Instagram Feed Table View](http://engineering.2359media.net/blog/2014/04/16/rebuilding-instagram-feed-table-view/).

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at the Instagram SDK I wrote for iOS apps to connect to the Instagram API. https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit
All you need to do is register your app with Instagram and after integrating the library, call the getUserFeed method to get an user's media feed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Instagram API. Especially at the `/users/user-id/media/recent` endpoint. Have a look at the link and read through the documentation:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent